# Why is \u000a a badchar?

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a string from hex:

```
import java.io.*;

public class a {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("something"); 
            w.println("\u0061\u0062\u000a");
            w.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {};
    }
}
```

But looks like "\u000a" is a badchar, it kept telling me unclosed string literal?

```
a.java:8: error: unclosed string literal
            w.println("\u0061\u0062\u000a");
```

Any idea what's wrong with it?

Running:

```
%> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: \u is not a special char. why you want to print Unicode?

Comment: @AlexGreg I need to put something unicode in it

Comment: Simply googling `\u000A` finds multiple answers. ;-)

Comment: see how it is internally working its breaking down to next line as its a linefeed. `\u000a`is same as `\n`

Answer (score 6):

That's a consequence of how `\u` is handled in Java. These unicode escapes are processed very early in the compilation, even before the tokenizer recognizes the string literal.

Therefore the code snippet is equivalent to:

```
w.println("ab
");
```

Which is clearly not correct.

To fix that use `\n` instead of `\u000a`.